# PHPMailer script stopped working with cryptic SMTP error messages

Tags: php, email, smtp, email-server, localhost

I am trying to send mail in a PHP script via the PHPMailer library. The following code has successfully sent emails in the past without warnings:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $subject, $message) {
  include("PHPMailer_5.2.3/class.phpmailer.php");
  include("PHPMailer_5.2.3/class.smtp.php");

  $email_config = parse_ini_file('email.cfg');
  $from  = $email_config['sender'];
  $alias = $email_config['alias' ];
  $smtp  = $email_config['host'  ];
  $port  = $email_config['port'  ];

  $mail             = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
  $mail->IsHTML(false);       // send as HTML?
  $mail->WordWrap   = 50;     // set word wrap

  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host       = $smtp;  // set the host SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = $port;  // set the host SMTP port

  $mail->Subject    = $subject;
  $mail->Body       = $message;
  $mail->SetFrom(   $from, $alias);
  $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $alias);
  $mail->AddAddress($mailto);
  $mail->AddAttachment($path, $filename);

  var_dump( $email_config );

  $sent = $mail->Send();
  if(!$sent)
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo ."\n";
  else
    echo "Message has been sent\n";
  return $sent;
}
```

Suddenly the automated reporting emails stopped showing up in people's inboxes and the following messages were generated:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 relay-8.dlfw.twtelecom.net ESMTP Postfix

<br />SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-relay-8.dlfw.twtelecom.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 25600000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN

<br />SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 Ok

<br />SMTP -> FROM SERVER:554 5.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Impossible, I am localhost

<br />SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Impossible, I am localhost

<br />SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: dataintegrity@corporate-domain.com
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: dataintegrity@corporate-domain.com<p>SMTP server error: 5.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Impossible, I am localhost
</p>

Mail Was NOT Successfully Sent!
```

Do you have any ideas on why the code stopped working?

Is the problem on my end or the remote mail server?

I have the following hostname configurations:

**/etc/hostname**

```
Dev07
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 lamp

#Required for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the remote server does not like the fact that your server is reporting that it is `localhost.localdomain` in the `HELO` you're sending.

This could result from the remote server configuring their SMTP service to reject invalid `HELO`s. It's also possible that something changed on your local server, such that the hostname is no longer configured correctly.

I would recommend [setting your hostname](https://www.movealong.org/hostname_printable.html) to something so that `sendmail` does not report as `localhost.localdomain`. While, you are at it, it's also a generally good idea to update `/etc/hosts` with the ip address, FQDN, and host name of the server.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/07/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-system/) on how to do it.

```
/etc/hostname:
hostname.domain.tld


/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain

1.2.3.4   hostname.domain.tld hostname
```

If you have a RedHat/CentOS based system, edit `/etc/sysconfig/network` and set:

```
HOSTNAME=hostname.domain.tld
```

Comment: Setting the server hostname is indeed the way to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I have updated my question with my host name configurations. Would you please suggest what specific changes to make?

Comment: @awashburn Did you restart all of the involved services?

Comment: @awashburn It also appears that you didn't update your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: I restarted the machine but the `/etc/hosts` & `/etc/hostname` edits did not affect the email SMTP response. Still says `FROM SERVER:554 5.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Impossible, I am localhost`

Comment: @awashburn You might try following this tutorial in case there was a step that was glossed over: http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/07/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-system/